# get order products categories in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have four tables
`Order`, `Category`, `Product`, `Order_Product`

each product belongs to a category
each order has many products

i save the order products in `order_product` table,

now in orderResource i want to have number of order->products in each category
so OrderResource should have

```
data 
[
{
 category_name: 'something',
productsCount: 3,
},
{
category_name: 'somethingelse',
productsCount: 2
}
]
```

how to do so ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources

Comment: @AnuratChapanond i know how to make resource, it's this specific relation/query that i cannot figure, how to count category->products which are related to the order

Comment: you can get the count of your products by category with $category->products->count()

Comment: @AnuratChapanond this would count all the category products, i only want to count products that are in the order

Comment: What you want is not possible, because we can get the products count using order because order can have multiple products, but we can't get product category like this. because categories are linked with the product, and one order can have multiple products. So categories also can be multiple.

Comment: @DilipHirapara it's not a direct relation but there is a relation, so maybe i just need to figure the right query to do so

Comment: Order to a product will have `belongsToMany`, and product to category will have `belongsTo` you can do, `Order::with('product.category')->withCount('product')->get()`

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get products from an order, and group the products by category and count the number of products in a category.

```
$orders = Order::with(['products' => function($query) {
    $query->groupBy('category_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) AS productsCount'), 'category_id')
        ->with('category');
}])
->get();

foreach($orders as $order) {
    foreach($order->products as $product) {
        $product->productsCount;
        $product->category->name;
    }
}
```